# Wait for thread to finish in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

I have some code which executes a download in a separate thread, created so that the JFrame GUI will continue to update during the download. But, the purpose is completely defeated when I use Thread.join(), as it causes the GUI to stop updating. I need a way to wait for the thread to finish and still update the GUI.

Comment: Check [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the task that does the download also fire an event to the GUI.

For example:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // do your download

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            // call some method to tell the GUI that the download finished.
         }
      });
   }
};
```

and then to run it, either use an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) (preferred method) or a raw thread:

```
executor.execute(task);
```

or

```
new Thread(task).start();
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, you'd generally use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to do this kind of thing but you can also do the manual approach outlined above.

SwingWorker provides a `doInBackground` method where you would stick your download logic in, a `done` method where you would stick in code to notify the GUI that the download finished and a `get` method to get the result of `doInBackground` (if there was one).

E.g.,

```
class Downloader extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {
   @Override
   public Object doInBackground() {
       return doDownload();
   }

   @Override
   protected void done() {
       try { 
         frame.downloadDone(get());
       } catch (Exception ignore) {
       }
   }
}

(new Downloader()).execute();
```

Comment: Great answer, but the first solution only updates the GUI _after_ the Thread is complete, whereas I wish to do so when the download starts. I've already attempted the second solution, but it's extremely messy, and again, doesn't seem to work until after the download completes.

Comment: Can't you update the GUI right before you make the call to start the download as well then?

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason, it doesn't update. Here's the code I'm using:

`if (!lwjglZip.exists() || update) // both of these are true`
`progress = "Downloading LWJGL";`
`repaint();`
`// execute thread`

The progress variable is used in the paintComponent method as the string that should be drawn.

Comment: I ultimately solved the problem by using JComponent.paintImmediately, which fixed repaint() waiting too long so as to let the Thread interrupt it.

Comment: _JComponent.paintImmediately_ DON'T if you aren't on the EDT!